# Before_filter inverted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I'm currently user :is_logged? into my controller to check if the user is logged, but I want some areas be ONLY to unlogged users.

```
  private
  def is_logged?
    !!current_user
  end

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :is_logged?
  helper_method :current_user
```

Is there any way to make the before_filter evaluate the opposite.

Currenty :is_logged? returns true is it's logged and false otherwise.
I want it to return true if it's not logged and vice versa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you just keep one method for determining whether a user is logged in or not, and not duplicate code with `logged_in?` and `not_logged_in?` methods.  For simplicity and readability, perhaps something like:

```
private

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
  helper_method :logged_in?
```

Then, when you want to do something with users who *are* logged in:

```
if logged_in?
  # do something for logged in users
end
```

And to do something specifically with users who *are not* logged in:

```
unless logged_in?
  # do something for users who are not logged in.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to simplify this, but for learning purposes I think this will do.

```
def not_logged_in?
  if defined? current_user
    current_user.nil?
  else
    true
  end
end
```